# C# Object being duplicated into List<T>

Tags: c#, winforms

This is such a silly problem for me to have, but I'm just stumped.

I'm retrieving data from a database, creating an object for each row of data obtained from the database, and adding that object to a List.

The problem is that each time I add the new object to the List, all other objects that are already in the list "change" to match the new one being added.

I.e. If the data I obtain (say a Name) is:
Ben/Fred/Holly

and I create a new object and add to the list each time, the list will progress as follows:

(first iteration)
Ben

(second iteration)
Fred
Fred

(third iteration)
Holly
Holly
Holly

I know the common answer to this is that I'm not creating a new object but just amending an existing one, but I DO create a new object. Here is the code:

```
List<Classes.User> users = new List<Classes.User>();            
        try
        {
            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM BenPoint_Users WHERE iEnabled=" + enabled;
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if(reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        Classes.User user = new Classes.User();
                        user.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["iUserID"].ToString());
                        user.UserName = reader["sUsername"].ToString().Trim();
                        user.EmailAddress = reader["sEmailAddress"].ToString().Trim();
                        user.DateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dDateCreated"].ToString());
                        if (reader["dExpired"] != DBNull.Value)
                            user.DateExpired = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dExpired"].ToString());
                        user.IsEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["iEnabled"]);
                        user.UserType = reader["sType"].ToString().Trim();
                        users.Add(user);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
                command.Dispose();
            }
            return users;
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show `Classes.User` class. I bet you have static members.

Comment: What's the definition of `Classes.User`?

Comment: The only logical explanation is that your `Classes.User` has `static` properties/fields.

Comment: Holy shit. Yeah they're all static!
Obviously I'll change it now (I can't remember why I made them static in the first place). Can anyone shed light on why this happens even if I'm creating a new object?

Comment: @BennyO'Neill If something is static, it is by definition shared among all instances of the class that declares it.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks everyone! All working now :)